# How do I save a list item created by user in local storage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, html-lists

This is a chore list that should save the list items the user enters to local storage. Please help!

```
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const toDoList = document.querySelector("#list");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const newToDo = document.querySelector("#addToDo");
    const newLi = document.createElement("li");
    const newButton = document.createElement("button");
    newLi.innerText = newToDo.value;
    newButton.innerText = "Remove";
    localStorage.setItem('newitem', newLi.innerText)

    newLi.append(newButton);
    toDoList.append(newLi);
    form.reset();

    toDoList.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        if (event.target.tagName === "LI") {
            event.target.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
        } else if (event.target.tagName === "BUTTON") {
            event.target.parentNode.remove();
        } 
    });
    
});
```

Comment: When you set the item into `localStorage()`, you must either add a new key/value pair so as not to overwrite the first one or you must append new data on to the end of the value for the key that is already there. Otherwise, you'll only ever have the last chore stored.

Answer (score 0):

Experimente trocar a linha :

```
localStorage.setItem('newitem', newLi.innerText)
```

Por:

```
if(!localStorage.getItem('countItems'))
{
   //se não existe cria o contador
   localStorage.setItem('countItems',0);
}

let cont =parseInt( localStorage.getItem('countItems') , 10 );

localStorage.setItem('newitem-' + cont , newLi.innerText)

localStorage.setItem('countItems',cont+1);
```

Para saber quantos, você pega o valor de countItems, assim:

```
const quantidade = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('countItems'),10);
```

Para pegar os valores, você usa o index de cada item, assim:

```
 const item0 = localStorage.getItem('newitem-0');
  const item1 = localStorage.getItem('newitem-1');
```

Ou pode navegar entre os itens :

```
    const cont =parseInt( localStorage.getItem('countItems') , 10 );
    let index =0;

    while (index < cont)
   {
      let item = localStorage.getItem('newitem-' + index);
      console.log('Item ' + index + ' tem valor ' + item);
      index++;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make a new key/value pair every time a new item is added to the list. That way you aren't overwriting the last key/value pair that was written into `localStorage`.  You can simply name each key with a number appended to it that represents a counter of which key it is.

```js
let numKeys = null;  // Will store the # of keys in localStorage

const form = document.querySelector("form");
const toDoList = document.querySelector("#list");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const newToDo = document.querySelector("#addToDo");
    const newLi = document.createElement("li");
    const newButton = document.createElement("button");
    newLi.innerText = newToDo.value;
    newButton.innerText = "Remove";
    
    numKeys = localStorage.length;  // Get the # of keys already in localStorage
    
    // Create a new key so as not to overwrite existing ones
    localStorage.setItem('newitem' + (numKeys + 1), newLi.innerText)

    newLi.append(newButton);
    toDoList.append(newLi);
    form.reset();

    toDoList.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        if (event.target.tagName === "LI") {
            event.target.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
        } else if (event.target.tagName === "BUTTON") {
            event.target.parentNode.remove();
        } 
    });
    
});
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Emi You're welcome. Please consider up voting the answer and marking it as "the" answer by clicking the check mark at the top left of the answer.